# Converting WCF service to asmx

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asmx

I develop a `WCF` service using c#(`nettcpbinding`), I want use it in an php program, so I think I have to change it to standard webservice, How can I Convert this wcf service to web service?(asmx)

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.  Expose the service over `basicHttpBinding` and you should be fine.  `netTcpBinding` is only for .NET; all you need to do is change the binding (or add another endpoint with `basicHttpBinding`, **NOT** convert the WCF service to a legacy ASMX service.

Comment: WCF ***IS*** the new standard for web services ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to convert it to asmx. You can just create another endpoint with `BasicHttpBinding` or `WebHttpBinding`.

Check out this article on why not to use asmx services:

http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/

Comment: `webHttpBinding` is for REST.  `basicHttpBinding` is probably what OP needs.

Comment: Yes if he wants to use REST he can use it with php..

Comment: My point is that the service OP wrote is most likely a SOAP service (since it's using `netTcpBinding`); there would have to be changes to make it a REST service, so `basicHttpBinding` is most likely the one needed.

Comment: Most likely??? Why assume??

Comment: It's a very valid assumption - OP stated that they were using `netTcpBinding`, which will not work for REST services, and they were asking if they should convert it to an ASMX service, which is SOAP 1.1.  It's not an assumption - it's a very valid guess based on the information presented in the question.